# Traefik is failing to distribute traffic between multiple host URLs

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, traefik-ingress

We have two environments, `dev` and `qa`. When we deploy the Ingress resources, we are only able to access whichever environment was deployed first. Why is this happening?

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: dev-ingress
  namespace: dev
  annotations:
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.entrypoints: web

spec:
  rules:
    - host: dev.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: dev
              servicePort: 80
---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: dev
  namespace: dev
  labels:
    app: dev
    name: dev

spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: dev
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: dev
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: devdev
          image: dev/dev
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: dev

spec:
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
  selector:
    app: dev
```